# Iter-selection data from a row-list and multiply each value with multiple csv files in order , Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, arraylist, multiplication

I have multiple csv files can be read in order using glob in pandas. Each file should multiply with a value from a list in order. Here is the code I wrote to read the whole csv file:

```
#list file
list = np.loadtxt('list.txt')
list  

source = r"e*.csv"
sorted_files =  glob.iglob(source)


i = 1
for fname in natsorted (sorted_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df
```

example from files and list are attached.
Note:
each csv file is a sheet of 110 columns*154 rows

`part of the files`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozAf.png)
[list file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWeeI.png)

I expect that and so on for all files:

[expect results for all files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk1pG.png)

Comment: Please don't use images of files/code/etc. Format them into the question

Comment: Thanks,. Please let me know the best format you normally use

Comment: You can use backticks (\`) to surround single lines of code. You can use triple backticks (\`\`\`), or code fences, to surround blocks of code

Comment: I am still beginner here, can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! First of all, 'list' is a pre-defined **keyword** and you **must not** use the same for your variable names. Now, modifying some portions of your code-

```
li = np.loadtxt('list.txt')
source = r"e*.csv"
sorted_files =  glob.iglob(source)
```

I was able to achieve (hopefully) your expected result:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
filenames = [file for file in sorted_files]
for i in range(len(li)):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(filenames[i])
    temp_df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df*li[i]])
```

The output is a dataframe with 154*number_of_csv_files x 110 columns multiplied by the number in the list.

Comment: I will run the code now

Comment: Update me with the results!

Comment: The code worked fine , but when it comes to file number 177, I had some issues with nan values

Comment: Not sure how share the results

Comment: The code works fine like that
df = pd.DataFrame()
filenames = [file for file in sorted_files]
for i in range(len(li)):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(filenames[i])
    df = pd.concat([temp_df*li[i]],axis =0)

Comment: It must be because of the multiplication between nan and our float number from the list. We might need to remove the nan values first before doing anything, i will try to update the code and you can try that?